# Dynamic Select Box showing previously set value

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to build a dynamic select box in a PHP form. I have it working in as much as it does change the value correctly, however, I can't get the box to show the correct value if a value has already been set. Currently, the value shown is always the first in the recordset used to populate the select list.

I'm sure it's pretty easy, but just looking for some quick guidance.

Here's the code for the select box

```html
<select name="select" id="select" title="<?php echo $row_ships['category']; ?>">
    <?php 
        do { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_categories['key']?>">
                <?php echo $row_categories['title']?>
            </option>
        <?php } 
        while ($row_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories));

        $rows = mysql_num_rows($categories);
        if ($rows > 0) {
            mysql_data_seek($categories, 0);
            $row_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories);
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Fred, sorry I should be more clear you're right. This is a snippet of code so perhaps things don't look defined, but the select box works, all I'm trying to do is make it show a previously selected item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try to set the selected option of the form-field after the form was submited previously, then this should point you in the right direction.

```
<?php
$rowSelected = '';
if ( isset( $_POST['select'] ) && $_POST['select'] == $row_categories['key'] ) {
    $rowSelected = 'selected="selected"'
}
?>
<option value="<?php echo( $row_categories['key'] ); ?>" <?php echo( $rowSelected ); ?>><?php echo $row_categories['title']?></option>
```

just put it inside your do-while-loop.

if your form uses GET, you have to replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`.